# Are custom sources supported with the IMFCaptureEngine?

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I've got a custom source that seams to work with a simple topology. When QueryInterface gets called the stack looks like this:

```
MySource.dll!MySource::QueryInterface(const _GUID & riid, void * * ppv) Line 83 C++
mfcore.dll!CMediaEventPtr::GetUnknown(struct IMFMediaEvent *,struct _GUID const &,void * *) Unknown
mfcore.dll!CMPSourceManager::OnNewStream()  Unknown
mfcore.dll!CMPSourceManager::OnSourceEvent()    Unknown
mfcore.dll!CMPSourceManager::OnSourceEventAsyncCallback::Invoke(struct IMFAsyncResult *)    Unknown
```

Using the same custom source without a topology, letting IMFCaptureEngine deal with that. When QueryInterface gets called the stack looks like this:

```
MySource.dll!MySource::QueryInterface(const _GUID & riid, void * * ppv) Line 42 C++
mfcore.dll!CMediaEventPtr::GetUnknown(struct IMFMediaEvent *,struct _GUID const &,void * *) Unknown
mfcore.dll!CSeqSourceWrap::HandleUpdatedStream(struct IMFMediaEvent *)  Unknown
mfcore.dll!CSeqSourceWrap::OnSourceEvent()  Unknown
mfcore.dll!CSeqSourceWrap::OnSourceEventAsyncCallback::Invoke(struct IMFAsyncResult *)  Unknown
```

In the topo case, I then get a call to GetStreamDescriptor and RequestSample and everything works.

```
MySourceCPP_COM.dll!MyStream::GetStreamDescriptor(IMFStreamDescriptor * * ppStreamDescriptor) Line 187  C++
mfcore.dll!CMPSourceManager::OnNewStream()  Unknown
mfcore.dll!CMPSourceManager::OnSourceEvent()    Unknown
mfcore.dll!CMPSourceManager::OnSourceEventAsyncCallback::Invoke(struct IMFAsyncResult *)    Unknown

MySourceCPP_COM.dll!MyStream::RequestSample(IUnknown * pToken) Line 208 C++
mfcore.dll!CMPSourceNodeInfo::RequestSample()   Unknown
mfcore.dll!CMPSourceNodeInfo::GenerateData()    Unknown
mfcore.dll!CMPSourceNodeInfo::ProcessSample()   Unknown
mfcore.dll!CMPWalker::ProcessCommands() Unknown
mfcore.dll!CMFMediaProcessor::ProcessSample()   Unknown
mfcore.dll!CMFMediaProcessorStream::_RequestSample()    Unknown
mfcore.dll!CMFMediaProcessorStream::RequestSample(struct IUnknown *)    Unknown
mfcore.dll!CBitPump::HandleSinkRequestSample()  Unknown
mfcore.dll!CBitPump::OnSinkEvent()  Unknown
mfcore.dll!CBitPump::OnSinkEventAsyncCallback::Invoke(struct IMFAsyncResult *)  Unknown
```

In the IMFCaptureEngine case I never get either call so data never flows.
I see the only difference is CMPSourceManager vs. CSeqSourceWrap.